# Will HDMI switch work on a higher frequency than claimed, if the resolution is lower?

Tags: hdmi

I have an HDMI monitor running at 1920x1080 74.97 Hz.

[This HDMI switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K2NZX8L) supports 4k@60hz. Will it work with my monitor?

The frequency is below mine, but the resolution of my monitor is below 4K. I suspect that these two factors will compensate each other and it will work with my monitor. Is this a correct reasoning?

Comment: I think it works with bandwidth so I would think yes

Answer (score 2):

The switch will simply output a lower refresh rate signal that's compatible with your display's refresh rate. However, verification is still required in practice.